# Rolling multiple data rows into 1 row with 'NA' or 'None' displayed if NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below statement to retrieve values in one line. 
I would like to display 'NA' or 'None' if there is no Value.
How do I include this in the below statement?

```
 STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) > 0 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' THEN
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 1 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '1 ' + pp.sPetType  ELSE
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 2 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '2 ' + pp.sPetType  + 's' ELSE
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 3 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '3 ' + pp.sPetType + 's'
          END END END ELSE 'None' END
          FROM person_pet pp
          WHERE t.hMyPerson = pp.hMyPerson
          GROUP BY pp.sPetType, pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal
          FOR XML Path('')), 1, 1, '')   [ServiceAnimal]
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be really helpful.  I added the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your STUFF column in an isnull? Like isnull('STUFF....', 'NA') This is how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly :

Add another CASE in the outer case like this:

```
CASE WHEN (pp.sPetType IS NULL OR pp.sPetType = '') THEN  'NA'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 STUFF((SELECT ISNULL(CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) > 0 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' THEN
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 1 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '1 ' + pp.sPetType  ELSE
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 2 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '2 ' + pp.sPetType  + 's' ELSE
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 3 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '3 ' + pp.sPetType + 's'
          END END END ELSE 'None' END,'None')
          FROM person_pet pp
          WHERE t.hMyPerson = pp.hMyPerson
          GROUP BY pp.sPetType, pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal
          FOR XML Path('')), 1, 1, '')   [ServiceAnimal]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are wanting the [ServiceAnimal] to have a result of 'NA' if it is null. This is a simple way to achieve that.

```
  ISNULL(STUFF((SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) > 0 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' THEN
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 1 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '1 ' + pp.sPetType  ELSE
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 2 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '2 ' + pp.sPetType  + 's' ELSE
          CASE WHEN COUNT(pp.sPetType) = 3 and pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal = 'Yes' then '; ' + '3 ' + pp.sPetType + 's'
          END END END ELSE 'None' END
          FROM person_pet pp
          WHERE t.hMyPerson = pp.hMyPerson
          GROUP BY pp.sPetType, pp.sPetIsServiceAnimal
          FOR XML Path('')), 1, 1, ''), 'NA') [ServiceAnimal]
```